# Laravel joining table relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm wanting to do a joining table but I'm not sure how to set up the relationship in laravel.

I have 3 tables, `products`, `categories`, and `product_categories`. product_categories will consist of the product ID and the category ID. How would I join theses up in a relationship in laravel so I can just call `$product->categories()` like a normal relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship will be **belongsToMany**.

Your `products` table would be

```
id | name
```

Your `categories` table would be

```
id |  name
```

your `product_categories` table would be

```
id | product_id | category_id
```

As per relationship in Laravel

**Product** Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','product_categories','product_id','category_id');
    }
}
```

**Category** Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
   
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','product_categories','category_id','product_id');
    }
}
```

In controller now

```
Product::with('categories')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

You can use belongsToMany on both `products` and `categories` and it would work. However you also should rename `product_categories` to follow the rule

> use singular table names in alphabetical order

this would be `category_product`

Comment: Thank you for your help!